# How to handle clicks from 2 listviews in 1 ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, handler

I'm a beginner programmer in Android and I guess this may not be the best practice but I have a list of news and categories. Each one with different parameters that go to another Activities.I wonder if anyone could be so kind and offer a workaround for this.

```
nuList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list2);
adapter1 = new CategsAdapter(UhoraYCategs.this, names);
nuList.setAdapter(adapter1); 
Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(nuList);
list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
adapter = new LazyAdapter(UhoraYCategs.this, imgs, titles, catg);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(list);
```

and the listeners for each one

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, UhoraList.class);
    i.putExtra("categoria", names[position]);
    i.putExtra("xml", urls[position]);
    startActivity(i);

}
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NewsIntentPave.class);
    i.putExtra("tit", (messages.get(position).getTitle()).toString());
    i.putExtra("descric",(messages.get(position).getDescription()).toString());
    i.putExtra("fecha", (messages.get(position).getDate()).toString());
    i.putExtra("foto", (messages.get(position).getFoto()).toString());
    i.putExtra("url", (messages.get(position).getLink()).toString());
    i.putExtra("banner", "uhora");
    startActivity(i);
}
```

How could I relate each listener with each list?. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why are you using 2 listview? just use one list view and make two different arraylist for set adapter. Its make easiest for your programming stuff.

Comment: could you help me out with some code? I'm not using one list because of the styles, can the 2 lists have different styles?.
They link to different places also.

Comment: So you have 2 listviews in the same listactivity? Are the listviews associated with each other? Are they the same length for instance?
If so you could create a general method for handling both click events which both listeners call. I think you're making things harder for yourself with 2 listviews ;)
Could you explain why you have to listviews instead of just one custom?

Comment: they are not the same length, one is for showing some images and text, and the other ones just text. each set of items point to different activities and a different set of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

When creating your views in the CursorAdapter call view.setTag("List A") or "List B" as appropriate then in your listener method

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    if(v.getTag().toString().equals("List A"))
    {
       // do list A stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // do list B stuff
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

A simpler way is to use the id of the parent control in a switch statement

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    switch(l.getId())
    {
       case R.id.list:
       {
         // do list A stuff
         break;
       }
       case R.id.list2:
       {
         // do list B stuff
         break;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: omg I love you so much, you have no idea how helpful this is with a deadline on me.
I still haven't figured out where exactly to call the view.setTag("List A") and stuff, but will get on it. 
thanks x1000000!

Comment: I'm only getting the property from one of the listviews, the other doesn't seem to return anything. Basically the ListView with the android:id="@android:id/list" as the identifier in the xml, the other that is identified as android:id="@+id/list2" doesn't returns anything =(

Comment: you need to add a listener to the list2 ... try `list2.setOnListItemClickListener(this);`

Comment: undefined for the type Listview ='(

Comment: remove "List" ... apologies try `list2.setOnItemClickListener(this);`

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance. I just can't get it to work. 
Now I'm getting 'The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (UhoraYCategs).
I tried changing the arguments of the class, but the app just crashes.
Tried letting the class implement 'OnItemClickListener' but it crashes too.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to do it, idk if it's the best way but it works. 
Basically on the 'onCreate' added the setOnItemClickListener to one Listview.

```
nuList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
lazyAdapter = new LazyAdapter(UhoraYCategs.this, imgs, titles, catg);
nuList.setAdapter(lazyAdapter); 

list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list2);
adapter = new CategsAdapter(UhoraYCategs.this, names);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){
        Intent i = new Intent(UhoraYCategs.this, UhoraList.class);
        i.putExtra("categoria", names[position]);
        i.putExtra("xml", urls[position]);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}); 
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And worked the other Listview with the regular listener.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NewsIntentPave.class);
    i.putExtra("tit", (messages.get(position).getTitle()).toString());
    i.putExtra("descric", (messages.get(position).getDescription()).toString());
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Thanks a lot to Merlin for all the help.